# Creating and Moving an Invisible file with OS X 10.8 Terminal

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion, hidden-files

I'm fairly new to using the terminal, but have so far figured out through various forums how to hide a file from the Finder, but once hidden, I'm obviously unable to move it to the flash drive I want to keep it on, and I can't figure out any way hide the file after it's moved off of the internal drive.  I'm using the command line:

```
Computer-name:~ User$ chflags hidden /users/me/desktop/filename.txt
```

How do I move the file once it's hidden, or how would I alter the command to hide the file after it's been moved to the flash drive?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the [faq]. This question is off topic here, try [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com) or [su].

Answer (score 1):

Definitely this is an AskDifferent ( https://apple.stackexchange.com/ ) kind of question but at the same time, it's pretty straightforward to answer.

1)  simply move the file to your flash drive

and then

2) hide it after it's copied /moved to the flash drive using "`chflags hidden`" and the path to where it lives on the flash drive. Another option is to use "`SetFile -aV path/to/file.txt`"

And just because it's hidden from the Finder doesn't mean you can't see it when you type in "`ls`" in Terminal.  So you can reverse the steps and copy after you make the file invisible.