# Objective-C Hidden files

Tags: objective-c, file, hidden

I need to have 2 methods : one for knowing if a file is hidden and the other one to set a file as hidden. I didn't get the aswer in developper documentation...

Anybody?

Thanks a lot !
Jérôme

Comment: It's in there. [Look just a](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH6-SW12) little [bit harder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files that begin with a "." will be hidden in Finder by default, so you could test if the file start with a dot, for example :

```
NSString* filename = //Something
if([string hasPrefix:@"."]) {
  //The file is hidden
}
```

To make the file invisible you could rename the file prepending a period to the name.

Comment: Sure but is there an attribute "hidden" for any file ?

Comment: Yes, [there is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755579/creating-and-moving-an-invisible-file-with-os-x-10-8-terminal), @user2600797.

Comment: @user2600797 actually that's NOT a file attribute, but rather a shell/BSD common-line thing. in the list of file attributes I haven't yet found a "hidden" attribute. There is only that unix convention of not showing in the UI (or ls if you consider the Terminal some kind of UI) files whose name begins with dot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSFileManager` to list files in a directory.

```
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:(NSString*)path];

NSArray *filteredContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:directoryURL
         includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLNameKey]
                            options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                              error:nil];
```

With the `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles` option specified, it will skip all hidden files in the directory. You can then perform a similar method, one that returns all files in a directory.

```
NSArray *allContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *path) error:nil];
```

Whatever files are in `allContents` that aren't in `filteredContents` will presumably be hidden files.

Comment: but that would not help write the required methods: one to tell you if a single file is hidden (or do you recommend this trick of comparing 2 iterations of parent directory, just to see if a specific file is hidden?) and how to MAKE a file hidden.