# Check if a file or directory is hidden

Tags: node.js, swift, objective-c, macos

On Mac, the first case, if the name of a file or dir is start with the ".", then it is hidden.

another case, for example:

```
/Users/USER_NAME/Library
/bin
```

Their names do not start with ".", but their is hidden.

I got all attributes of '/Users/USER_NAME/Library':

objective-c

```
NSError * error;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

output:

```
{
    NSFileCreationDate = "2019-06-04 23:44:56 +0000";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 20;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = staff;
    NSFileModificationDate = "2021-10-31 18:47:57 +0000";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = xxxxxxxx;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 448;
    NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 79;
    NSFileSize = 2528;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 360719;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 16777221;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
}
```

I not found whether to hide related attribute(s).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902169/objective-c-hidden-files

Comment: @Cristik the answer only checked name whether  to start with ".".

Comment: @CaoYongFeng if the file name begins with a period the attribute isHidden won't have any effect

Comment: @LeoDabus "/bin" is not start with ".", it is hidden.

Comment: @CaoYongFeng check my post bellow. Btw you should use URLs instead of paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the fileURL resource key [isHiddenKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/1411238-ishiddenkey) if the fileURL is hidden or not. Note that if the file name begins with a period changing the `isHidden` value won't have any effect:

From the docs

> If the resource is hidden because its name begins with a period, setting this value has no effect.

---

```
extension URL {
    var isHidden: Bool {
        get { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.isHiddenKey]))?.isHidden == true }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.isHidden = newValue
            do {
                try setResourceValues(resourceValues)
            } catch {
                print("isHidden error:", error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```